# Odoo Custom Module - First Steps failed by model_id

Tags: module, odoo

on my work we have a new ERP-System with based on odoo. I have tried to write my own module to try to understand the workwise of odoo, but it fails by the file ir.model.access.csv and i don´t know what is the issue.
Here are my files:
music.py

```
from odoo import fields, models

class Music(models.Model):
    _name = "music"
    _description = "This is Music"

    name = fields.Char("Name")
    title = fields.Char("Title")
    genre = fields.Char("Genre")
```

my view:

```
    <odoo>
    <data>
        <!--name, model und arch bezieht sich auf irgendwas im model ir.ui.view-->
        <!--name = eindeutiger name-->
        <!--model = der angegebene name in der Klasse-->
        <record id="music_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">music.tree.view</field>
            <field name="model">music</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree>
                    <field name="name"/>
                    <field name="title"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="music_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">music.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">music</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Music">
                    <group>
                        <field name="name"/>
                        <field name="title"/>
                        <field name="genre"/>
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record id="music_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Music</field>
            <field name="res_model">music</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>

        <menuItem id="music_root_menu"
                    name="Music"
                    />
        
        <menuItem id="music_sub_root_menu"
                    name="All My Music"
                    parent="music_root_menu"
                    />
        
        <menuItem id="music_sub_root_menu"
                    action="music_action"
                    name="My Music List"
                    parent="music_sub_root_menu"
                    />

    </data>
</odoo>
```

and the file ir.model.access.csv

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_music,music,model_music,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

Do you need the other files too for help?

```
The exception is:

Exception: Laden des Moduls Music fehlgeschlagen: Datei Music\security/ir.model.access.csv konnte nicht verarbeitet werden
Kein passender Datensatz für externe ID „model_music.music“ in Feld „Model“ gefunden
Ein erforderlicher Wert für das Feld „Model“ (model_id) fehlt.

=> no value for the field model_id.
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The `ir.model.access.csv` should be loaded without any error unlike the view file, you have two errors: `element "menuItem" not allowed here` and the parent of the last menu is itself which is not allowed (`recursion`)

Comment: O.k. thank you. Where i have to define the menuItem? And why i get the error of ir.model.acce.csv? I don´t understand why.

Comment: And what should be in the __init__.py in music->models ?

Comment: You should change the parent of the last menu item, maybe to `music_root_menu`. The CSV file is ok

Comment: You import the file where you declared the model in `music->models->__init__.py` and also import the model in music ``__init__.py`` file (`from . import models`)

Comment: You should import music models in module ``__init__.py`` file (`from . import models`) not the Odoo models

Comment: Yes. The init files was incorrect. Another issue was the node menuItem. It should be menuitem.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is a special case when having only one word for a model name or just no `.` (dot) in the name of a model. On import something weird is happening and odoo tries to find an external id of a model which isn't there: `model_music.music`. I don't know the name of your module, but it should be something like `my_module.model_music`.

I've only found 2 to 3 models without `.` in Odoo's code, for example the model `website` in the website module. And odoo used the fully qualified external id for this model in its security file. So just try to do that, too:

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_music,music,my_module.model_music,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: My Modules name is only music. It was for testing to create a customer module. The issue was in the init files and another issue was the node menuItem.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping! Next question comes soon ;-)